# How to define range's end point as the last row with data?

Tags: excel, vba, range, vlookup

I am using vlookup, after finding it with lookup i am using autofill. In macro after the autofill code it finds the range and autofills it. But in terms of code's robustness it is not usefull because the range it finds sticks to the code. Basically,

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],Sheet1!C[-5]:C[4],7,FALSE)"
    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F502")
    Range("F2:F502").Select
```

is the original code, i just want to do Range("F2: last data")

Thanks in advance

Edit: Solved.

```
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row   


Range("F2").Select


        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],Sheet1!C[-5]:C[4],7,FALSE)"
       Range("F2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2", Cells(LastRow, 6))
```

I was trying to simplify the code but I guess I need to put this before every VLOOKUP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the last row used in **Column F**.

**Edit 1**: added `LastCol` (from row 2 in this example))

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],Sheet1!C[-5]:C[4],7,FALSE)"
Range("F2").Select

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

LastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, LastCol).End(xlUp).row

' assuming your data starts from row 2
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, LastCol), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
Range(Cells(2, LastCol), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Select
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, 

for finding last row, how can i automize the "F" part. Because data is really big.

Comment: it does not automate the F actually, in order to automate there shouldn't be any F's in the code. With this code it is not working even for autofill. But thanks for trying and for your time

Comment: @hakandeep it works when you have data in Column F , don't you ?

Comment: Cells and lastrow not working. It finds lastrow as 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the last row with `Rows.Count` and you can simplify a little by setting your range so you do not need to use `Autofill`:

```
Dim MyRange as Range: Set MyRange = Range("F2:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)

MyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "VLOOKUP(RC[-5],Sheet1!C[-5]:C[4],7,FALSE)"
```

Also, you should try to avoid using `Select`[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but i need to use select. Because data is transferred from sheet to sheet and I am using End property. I don't have much time also so generally I am using macro recording and trying to increase the code's flexibility with modifications. Also I think this code misses the changing cells within the formula since it searches for C2,C3,..

Comment: Also code only prints F2 and F3 as vlookup name. It should be taken the data from F column from sheet1 to vlookup on F column on sheet 2. I put sheet1.range=("F2:F" but i think this part is not working. That is my all problem. I want it from F2 to last row that contains data